# Graphics debugging of Windows Store Apps in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, directx

**Summary**: How can I capture a frame for a Windows App and see the Direct3D calls that are made.

**Details**:

I'm trying to look at the DirectX calls that are made by GFXBench running in Windows 8.  In Visual Studio 2012 I can choose `DEBUG->Graphics->Debug Installed App Package`.  From there I can run the app.  However, the typical way to capture a frame in visual studio is to press `Print Screen.`  But when the Windows App launches it takes up the entire screen (as it's designed to do), and if I press `print screen` Windows captures a screenshot rather than Visual Studio capturing the trace of DirectX calls for the frame.

Is it possible to capture frames from a Windows App?  If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was selecting `GPU Only` because that was what I thought I was interested in.  However, that option does not allow for capturing frames.  The correct choice for the app I was running is `Native Only` although other options might also work.